# Change user's salted password from external PHP application in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've upgraded a TYPO3 site from 6.2 to 7.6 LTS which now runs under a PHP 7.0 installation just fine. I also have a PHP application which I use to change a user's salted password (fe_user). The following code in my application worked fine under the 6.2 installation:

```
require Yii::app()->params['typo3Path'] . 'typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php';
define('TYPO3_MODE', 'FE');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance()
    baseSetup('typo3/')
    loadConfigurationAndInitialize();
```

But now in the 7.6 installation, this code throws an exception:

```
Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\ApplicationContext' not found
```

Any ideas? Is there an "official" way to change a TYPO3 user's password from an API or something?

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no official API to change a User's password from outside of
   Typo3.
2. If you absolutely must handle user data outside of Typo3, you should
   probably look into switching to an external authentication mechanism
   alltogether. There's a bunch of extensions for that in the TER
   (OpenID, LDAP/Active Directory, SAML come to mind)
3. If you still want to go the unofficial route, why would you
   instantiate the whole Typo3 Framework when you already have another
   framework in place? Just access the database table and change the
   password. The algorithm used to build the password hash is properly
   documented. By default Typo3 uses PBKDF2 to generate the hash these
   days.

Comment: The solution that I followed at the end, was to copy the code from the salted extension in my own class and use the same encryption method (md5 salted) to change a user's password. So no TYPO3 bootstrapping was actually needed. Thank you for your comment anyway.